# CGImage/UIImage lazily loading on UI thread causes stutter

Tags: iphone, uiimage, lazy-loading, exc-bad-access, cgimage

My program displays a horizontal scrolling surface tiled with UIImageViews from left to right.  Code runs on the UI thread to ensure that newly-visible UIImageViews have a freshly loaded UIImage assigned to them.  The loading happens on a background thread.

Everything works almost fine, except there is a stutter as each image becomes visible.  At first I thought my background worker was locking something in the UI thread.  I spent a lot of time looking at it and eventually realized that the UIImage is doing some extra lazy processing on the UI thread when it first becomes visible.  This puzzles me, since my worker thread has explicit code for decompressing JPEG data.

Anyway, on a hunch I wrote some code to render into a temporary graphics context on the background thread and - sure enough, the stutter went away.  The UIImage is now being pre-loaded on my worker thread.  So far so good.

The issue is that my new "force lazy load of image" method is unreliable.  It causes intermittent EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I have no idea what UIImage is actually doing behind the scenes.  Perhaps it is decompressing the JPEG data.  Anyway, the method is:

```
+ (void)forceLazyLoadOfImage: (UIImage*)image
{
 CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

 CGFloat currentWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
 CGFloat currentHeight = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 CGFloat scaleRatioX = bounds.size.width / currentWidth;
 CGFloat scaleRatioY = bounds.size.height / currentHeight;

 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatioX, -scaleRatioY);
 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -currentHeight);
 CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
 CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, currentWidth, currentHeight), imgRef);

 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

And the EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens on the CGContextDrawImage line.  QUESTION 1: Am I allowed to do this on a thread other than the UI thread?  QUESTION 2: What is the UIImage actually "pre-loading"?  QUESTION 3: What is the official way to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading all that, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `UIGraphics*` methods are designed to be called from the main thread only. They are probably the source of your trouble.

You can replace `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` with a call to `CGBitmapContextCreate()`; it's a little more involved (you need to create a color space, figure out the right sized buffer to create, and allocate it yourself). The `CG*` methods are fine to run from a different thread.

---

I'm not sure how you're initializing UIImage, but if you're doing it with `imageNamed:` or `initWithFile:` then you might be able to force it to load by loading the data yourself and then calling `initWithData:`. The stutter is probably due to lazy file I/O, so initializing it with a data object won't give it the option of reading from a file.

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to help with this.  I eventually came to this realization.  I can only imagine what kind of nasty non-threadsafe caching is going on inside those UI* methods.  My interface is now stutter free.....

Comment: I'm confused... you're saying imageNamed: is causing lazy file IO but.. creating a data object won't? Or are you saying that you should have the data objects pooled somewhere to be drawn from when appropriate?

Comment: Jasconius: If you create a UIImage object and give it the path to a file, it may not load the whole image into memory until you draw it. If you load the file into memory using an NSData object, then pass THAT to UIImage, it has no choice but to keep it in memory. What's best depends on the specific situation.

Answer (score 22):

I've had the same stuttering problem, with some help I figured out the proper solution here: [Non-lazy image loading in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266272/non-lazy-image-loading-in-ios)

Two important things to mention:

- Don't use UIKit methods in a worker-thread. Use CoreGraphics instead.
- Even if you have a background thread for loading and decompressing images, you'll still have a little stutter if you use the wrong bitmask for your CGBitmapContext. This are the options you have to choose (it's still a bit unclear to me why):

-

```
CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBuffer, width, height, 8, width*4, colourSpace,
                          kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
```

I've posted a sample project here: [SwapTest](http://www.jasamer.com/files/SwapTest-Fixed.zip), it has about the same performace as Apples' Photos app for loading/displaying images.

Comment: I can't comprehend why you had 0 upvotes. Your solution was the only one that worked for me. I'd give you 10 upvotes if I could. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 11):

I used @jasamer's SwapTest UIImage category to force load my large UIImage (about 3000x2100 px) in a worker thread (with NSOperationQueue). This reduces the stutter time when setting the image into the UIImageView to an acceptable value (about 0.5 sec on iPad1).

Here is SwapTest UIImage category... thanks again @jasamer :)

UIImage+ImmediateLoading.h file

```
@interface UIImage (UIImage_ImmediateLoading)

- (UIImage*)initImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)path;
+ (UIImage*)imageImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)path;

@end
```

UIImage+ImmediateLoading.m file

```
#import "UIImage+ImmediateLoading.h"

@implementation UIImage (UIImage_ImmediateLoading)

+ (UIImage*)imageImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)path {
    return [[[UIImage alloc] initImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile: path] autorelease];
}

- (UIImage*)initImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:(NSString*)path {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef));
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                       rect.size.width,
                                                       rect.size.height,
                                                       CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                       CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef),
                                                       CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
                                                       );
    //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little are the bit flags required so that the main thread doesn't have any conversions to do.

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, rect, imageRef);
    CGImageRef decompressedImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    UIImage* decompressedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: decompressedImageRef];
    CGImageRelease(decompressedImageRef);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
    [image release];

    return decompressedImage;
}

@end
```

And this is how I create NSOpeationQueue and set the image on main thread...

```
// Loads low-res UIImage at a given index and start loading a hi-res one in background.
// After finish loading, set the hi-res image into UIImageView. Remember, we need to 
// update UI "on main thread" otherwise its result will be unpredictable.
-(void)loadPageAtIndex:(int)index {
    prevPage = index;

    //load low-res
    imageViewForZoom.image = [images objectAtIndex:index];

    //load hi-res on another thread
    [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];  
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [NSInvocationOperation alloc];
    filePath = [imagesHD objectAtIndex:index];
    operation = [operation initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadHiResImage:) object:[imagesHD objectAtIndex:index]];
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
    operation = nil;
}

// background thread
-(void)loadHiResImage:(NSString*)file {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"loading");

    // This doesn't load the image.
    //UIImage *hiRes = [UIImage imageNamed:file];

    // Loads UIImage. There is no UI updating so it should be thread-safe.
    UIImage *hiRes = [[UIImage alloc] initImmediateLoadWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType: nil]];

    [imageViewForZoom performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:hiRes waitUntilDone:NO];

    [hiRes release];
    NSLog(@"loaded");
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: There still is a call to UIImage in a thread other than your main thread, so this solution isn't safe.

Comment: You could use CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([path UTF8String]), NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault) instead of the UIImage

Comment: @JorisMans how is calling UIImage outside main thread not safe?

Comment: UIImage = UIKit. You are not allowed to use UIKit on another thread

Comment: No, only **UI updating** are not allowed on another thread. Here I only create a UIImage instance so it should be fine. Moreover, it is fairly a common practice to load images in the background.

Comment: @Hlung is right. From the [UIImage class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `It also means that image objects are themselves safe to use from any thread.`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, even though I initialized the image using data. (I guess the data is loaded lazily, too?) I’ve succeeded to force decoding using the following category:

```
@interface UIImage (Loading)
- (void) forceLoad;
@end

@implementation UIImage (Loading)

- (void) forceLoad
{
    const CGImageRef cgImage = [self CGImage];  

    const int width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    const int height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    const CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(cgImage);
    const CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        NULL, /* Where to store the data. NULL = don’t care */
        width, height, /* width & height */
        8, width * 4, /* bits per component, bytes per row */
        colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}

@end
```