# (iphone) UIImage imageWithData: should be called in mainthread only in ios3.1?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiimage

I read UIImage is thread safe from ios4.x.

Wonder if imageWithData: should be called from main thread only in ios3.x?

-- edit

Should allocing UIImage also be done in main thread only in ios3.x?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

UIImage is thread safe but UIImageView is not (in iOS4). If you need to support iOS3.x then you need to do all UIImage operations in main thread as well.

Edit: Adding a link to the
[already answered question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904575/decode-images-in-background-thread)

Comment: Please see the following question which is pretty much the same as what you're asking. Don't want to make another copy of answer here so here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904575/decode-images-in-background-thread