# UIImage + NSCache vs. [UIImage imageNamed:]

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimage

i have a performance Problem, if i load an JPG (and yes i can't provide any PNG File Format in the App) Image from the Disk with `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: ]`, store the UIImage in a global NSCache and use the Cached Image in `[UITableViewCell drawRect: ]`. This approach is much slower than user  `[UIImage imagedNamed:]` .

If have analyzed the performance with the Instruments "Time Profile" and as you can see in the first picture the JPEG is always decode in the `[DBArtistTableViewCell drawRect:]`.
In the second picture with the `[UIImage imageNamed:]` solution the JPG will not decompressed.

`NSCache` + `UIImage` Solution:
[image: NSCache + UIImage]

`[UIImage imageNamed]` Solution
[image: UIImage imageNamed]

The short question is: Why is the `UIImage` + `NSCache` solution slower than the `[UIImage imageNamed:]` solution and what is the magic with `[UIImage imageNamed:]` Method (yes i know the caching, but what is the rest of the magic) ?

Thx for Helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason is that `UIImage imageNamed` causes the data to be decompressed and stored in it's cache, whereas `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile` loads the compressed data, but doesn't decompress it until you need to display it.

Comment: is there a way to decompress the UIImage from [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile] by myself?

Comment: Theres some discussion in the comments on this question that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815476/cgimage-uiimage-lazily-loading-on-ui-thread-causes-stutter